# Spring - injeção de dependência em Thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Preciso de uma pequena ajuda.

Estou fazendo uns testes com Spring Boot e tenho minhas services + alguns processos que quero executar em thread. Cada thread vai executar sua própria service.

Quando faço a injeção de dependência da service pela minha classe principal e passo no construtor da thread, tudo funciona da forma como eu quero.

Porém, não gosto da forma como está implementado e creio que existe uma forma mais bonita de fazer isso, ou seja, a própria thread injetar a service que vai utilizar.

Como está hoje:

**Classe Principal:**

```
@Autowired
ITesteService service;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BaseUnicaApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                    executor.submit(new TesteProcessor(service));

}
```

**Thread**

```
public class TesteProcessor implements Runnable  {

private ITesteService service;

public TesteProcessor() {
    this.service = service;
}

public void run() {

    service.save
```

Já tentei fazer a injeção de dependencia direto na service, mas ocorre NullPointer quando utilizo a service.

```
public class TesteProcessor implements Runnable  {

@Autowired
private ITesteService service;

public TesteProcessor() {
}

public void run() {
    service.save
}
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `@Async` e fazer a configuração via `Bean`, podendo usar assim injeção de dependência sem problemas.

Ficaria assim:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

E para usar:

```
 @Service
 public class ClassePrincipalService {

     @Autowired
     private TesteProcessorService testeProcessorService ;

     public void save() {
         // cada chamada aqui será assyncrona, abrindo uma nova thread
         testeProcessorService.run();
     }
 }
```

E agora, com injeção de dependência:

```
 @Service
 public class TesteProcessorService {

      @Autowired
      private ITesteService service;

      @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
      public void run() { service.save(); }
 }
```